# Regex javascript remove _ -

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to replace all _ - . from a String with a white space. This is what I've came up with :

```
mystring.replace(/_|-|\\. /g, ' ');
```

The dot is not being removed but _ and - are. How to remove the dot as well ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"aaa_aaa-aaa.aaaa".replace(/_|-|\./g, ' ');`

works for me.  Note I used a single escape `\` and got rid of your blank space before the closing `/`.

Comment: Thank you, indeed i wasn't very far.. :)

Comment: eric, you weren't far, but @kolink has the superior answer.  I would do that as it's somewhat simpler.

Comment: Yup used his code, but due to the nature of my question, i vote you up because i could understand my mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `/[-_.]/g` instead - with the dot in a character class you don't need to escape it.

(The original problem what that you were double-escaping it so it was looking for a literal backslash followed by any character.

Comment: Plus, you get an emoticon for free.